# Understanding the limit $n \to \infty$ of the sequence $a_n := \frac{n!}{3^n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I want to know the limit $n \to \infty$ of the sequence

$$a_n := \frac{n!}{3^n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I have seen somewhere that 
$$a_n:=\frac{n!}{3^n}\implies\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{(n+1)!}{3^{n+1}}\frac{n!}{3^n}=\frac{n+1}{3}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty $$

Is that correct? Can someone tell me how you get from $\frac{(n+1)!}{3^{n+1}}\frac{n!}{3^n} \text{ to }\frac{n+1}{3}$?

Comment: It is division but not multiplication for $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$

Comment: It's supposed to be $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and it's supposed to be $\frac{(n+1)!}{3^{n+1}}\div \frac{n!}{3^n}$. Does that help?

Comment: @Arthur reverse the fraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{(n+1)! 3^n}{n! 3^{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{3}$

Since $(n+1)!=(n+1)(n!)$